# Are the VS2015 64-bit MFC symbols on the Microsoft Symbol Server?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, pdb-files, symbol-server

I'm trying to debug a crash/minidump from a customer who was running 64-bit software.  The symbols for mfc140u.dll are not loading even though I'm downloading from the "Microsoft Symbols Servers" in Symbol Settings.  Looking at the symbol cache, the PDBs for mfc140u.i386 are available.

Is there any way to confirm these symbols are available from that server?  Are there instructions to get them from somewhere else that I need to find?

In C:\Windows\System32 the mfc140u.dll is version 14.0.23918.0.  The dump file is looking for version 14.00.23506.0.

The symbols for these DLLs are also not loading:

- msvcp140.dll (looking for 14.00.23506.0)
- VCRUNTIME140.dll (looking for 14.00.23506.0)

Comment: I'm getting mfc140u.i386.pdb\1D0938D1EB0C400E8301075B3E4756C82\mfc140u.i386.pdb just fine.  Right-click mfx140u.dll in the Debug > Windows > Modules window and select Symbol Load Information to properly document your question.

Comment: Hans, it simply says, under Information: "No matching binary found."  Isn't the i386 PDB we have going to be for debugging the 32-bit MFC DLL?

Comment: I have no idea if you are talking about the subdirectory or the actual file, they have the same name.  Delete the ones you see from your symbol cache so the Symbol Load Information dialog tells you the whole story, including its attempts to download the file from the symbol server.

Comment: which version of mfc140u.dll do you use? I got a PDB: \mfc140u.amd64.pdb\AEE1E25C505146A789824BAF147713DC17\mfc140u.amd64.pdb

Comment: @magicandre1981 It needs 14.00.23506.0.  What version is yours?

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I was just looking at the name of the directory.  Emptied the symbol cache, and the Symbol Load Information is still not helpful.  FWIW the 32-bit mfc140u.i386.pdb directory has not returned.  Searching for a way to increase the verbosity.

Comment: is this file part of the VS2015 update1? I also have mfc140u.amd64.pdb\721B40B6E12F4A549D13695189CFD36917\mfc140u.amd64.pdb for version 14.0.23918.0.

Comment: @magicandre1981 From researching it a bit, yes, it seems build 23506 is Update 1 and 23918 is update 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm able to get all 3 PDBs with a tool called [PDB Downloader](https://github.com/rajkumar-rangaraj/PDB-Downloader/releases). Get them from my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7atgtgh31est893/AADcQsX_U1aqENgiNn18uGkra?dl=0) and put them into your local symbol cache folder.

Comment: I think what I really need is vc_redist.x64.exe for Visual Studio Update 1 (build 23506) (actually quite hard to find).  That is, I don't actually have the correct version of mfc140u.dll in C:\Windows\System32 right now.  My suspicion is that the symbol server will start to cooperate once I have that.  Thanks for your effort though, you pretty much got to the root of the problem by asking for a DLL version number (I wasn't thinking about the two updates VS2015 has been through).