# CMFCLinkCtrl throws runtime error when it is using with dll in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc, modal-dialog, controls

I have placed a CMFCLinkCtrl - (control to show the links in the dialog frame) in my modal dialog box application which works perfectly.
upon setting the SetURL("www.google.com") it could able to invoke it.

When i do the same in a dll (dialog box is part of dll) and when the user clicks the control, it is throwing an runtime exception and i could not able to debug it.

I have two questions, 
can we use the CMFCLinkCtrl controls inside a dll based out of dialog box?
if so, how to debug and find the issue?

error Image: [image: Exception window]

[image: Call stack]

thanks,
Saravana

Comment: *"i could not able to debug it"* - Why? Someone threatening you to **not** click the *Break* button? You dereference a null pointer. There's nothing more we can do to help.

Comment: I can do that, it is taking me to the place where I have called the DoModal() and not the exact place where the exception is. Like when i click the Lunk url button it has to call shellexecute command and open a window with the link i have set in SetURL()...

Comment: The exception is raised in *mfc140u.dll*. You have full source code for that module. Ask a developer to set up your development machine.

Comment: I'm using VS2015 update1 - and the redist is 14.0.23506, where can i download redist for 14.0.24720.00

Comment: i have used PDBDownloader and got the pdb file for mfc140u.dll and able to load the entire call stack... It is failing in hWnd is seams to be unused=??? is it that?

Comment: it is failed at 
<code>
void CCmdTarget::BeginWaitCursor()
 { AfxGetApp()->DoWaitCursor(1); } // this line
<code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some time I have removed the code

```
CWinApp theApp
```

from the dll implementation, since I'm not using it. That's the reason behind this error. When I added it back it is able to invoke the URL.

As I have mentioned it is get struck in the  below line, just explored more on why the failure of AfxGetApp() and found this reason.

`void CCmdTarget::BeginWaitCursor()
AfxGetApp()->DoWaitCursor(1)`

Comment: used this post to download the PDB downloader - thanks for the support http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391637/are-the-vs2015-64-bit-mfc-symbols-on-the-microsoft-symbol-server